# live preview of video processing in android app

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I'm building a video editing app and currently I am using **ffmpeg** for encoding and decoding process (my app can easily do the tasks where live preview is not required like reverse a video or apply filters like B/W or pick specific frames in video and some audio tasks etc)
but **Problem is that if user want to adjust the brightness or contrast of the video they require live preview of the video but that is not supported by ffmpeg** ffmpeg requires to encode the video before the preview 
**so my question is how can I achieve live preview with ffmpeg**

Thanks in advance (sorry for grammar related problems in the question)